# VNC Viewer won't connect

Tags: pi-3, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B I have been connecting to with VNC Viewer for over a month.

I use a virtual desktop.  Connect to the Pi with PuTTY and run the vncserver command in the terminal.  I usually get 192.168.1.181:1.

I open VNC Viewer 6.0.1 on my Windows 10 PC, connec to the above IP address and get "The connection was refused during establishment"

Connected the Pi with a monitor.  SSH is running.  VNC is running.  Don't see any issues.

I am lost on how to troubleshoot.  Any help would be great!  Thx.

Comment: Are you sure that you are connecting to the right port?

Comment: A reboot of the PI and a restart of the Windows 10 machine always "resets" everything.  Not sure why it becomes unresponsive, but this fixes it.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So can i write an answer you'll mark as correct for a few points?

Comment: I did try the steps you recommended in route to solving my problem.  I'll click the "check" on your answer.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting:

1. Make sure you've got the right device (run a port scanner)
2. Ssh into it and make sure your vnc server is up to date (if using tightvnc or something else from apt-get, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. <strike>Short all gpio pins, break raspberry pi in half</strike> See if your vnc viewer has received any updates and attempt to downgrade if it has. Otherwise, see if it has any updates and install them.
4. Check if that's the right port

I didn't understand the thing about the virtual desktop. Is it running on the Windows 10 PC? If so, make sure your firewall (on the computer) isn't allowing outgoing connections.

Comment: thanks for the rep! Also, I'm interested in why the restart of the windows 10 machine helped -- did you just install software and not restart the computer -- leading to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and had to install the desktop for my lite instance:

```
sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods
```